# How to await for network connectivity status in Flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await, build, internet-connection, network-connection

I have used `connectivity_plus` and `internet_connection_checker` packages to check the Internet connectivity.

The problem that occurred was the app worked perfectly fine as expected when the app started with Internet on state. But when the app is opened with the Internet connection off, the dialog isn't shown!!

I assume this is happening because the build method is called before the stream of Internet is listened to.

Code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late StreamSubscription subscription;
  bool isDeviceConnected = false;
  bool isAlertSet = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getConnectivity();
    super.initState();
  }

  getConnectivity() {
    subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen(
      (ConnectivityResult result) async {
        isDeviceConnected = await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
        if (!isDeviceConnected && isAlertSet == false) {
          showDialogBox();
          setState(() {
            isAlertSet = true;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      ...
    );
  }

  showDialogBox() => showDialog(/* no internet dialog */)
```

**Extending the question**: Is it assured that this works for all the pages?

- if yes, how?
- if not, how can I overcome this?

Comment: You can use future builder

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to listen for internet connectivity in your app first screen which is probably app.dart

   ```
    GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

    final noInternet = NoInternetDialog();

    class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     State<TestApp> createState() => _TestAppState();
     }

    class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       checkInternetConnectivity();
      }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(...);
    }

   Future<void> checkInternetConnectivity() async {
     Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.getInternetStatus().listen((event) 
      {
      if (event == InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected) {
        if (!noInternet.isShowing) {
          noInternet.showNoInternet();
        }
      }
      });
     }
    }
   ```
2. Make the screen stateful in which you are calling MaterialApp and in initState of that class check for your internet connection, like above
3. You are saying how can I show dialog when internet connection changes for that you have to create a Generic class or extension which you can on connectivity change. **You have to pass context to that dialogue using NavigatorKey**

   ```
   class NoInternetDialog {
    bool _isShowing = false;
    NoInternetDialog();

    void dismiss() {
     navigatorKey.currentState?.pop();
     }

     bool get isShowing => _isShowing;

     set setIsShowing(bool value) {
    _isShowing = value;
    }

    Future showNoInternet() {
     return showDialog(
      context: navigatorKey.currentState!.overlay!.context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
      builder: (ctx) {
        setIsShowing = true;
        return AlertDialog(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0.h),
          content: Container(...),
        );
      },
     );
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't work ! for both the cases ; i) open app with internet on ii) open app without internet on

Comment: check that your app is listening internet connectivity of not first

Answer (score 0):

Use [checkConnectivity](https://pub.dev/documentation/connectivity_plus/latest/connectivity_plus/Connectivity/checkConnectivity.html) to check current status. Only changes are exposed to the stream.

```
final connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
```

Comment: Please be descriptive about your answer. Its just a statement , not an answer to my question